# Frosted Glass Effect in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, ios7, javafx-2, blur

I'm making an iOS7-themed JavaFX2/FXML project and I was wondering how I could make a Rectangle object have a iOS7-like frosted glass effect.

I'd also like it to have a small shadow. This is tricky, since you might be able to see the shadow behind the semi-transparent object. I'd just like it to be present around the edges.

Is this possible? Here's a picture showing the desired effect (not including the small drop-shadow):

[image: I'd like it to look like this]

UPDATE: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663681/javafx-effect-on-background) a continuation of the issue. This is going  to look amazing :D.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Sample Solution**

[image: frost]

Run the program below and scroll or swipe up to show the glass pane.

The purpose of the program is just to sample the techniques involved not to act as a general purpose library for the frost effect.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

// slides a frost pane in on scroll or swipe up; slides it out on scroll or swipe down.
public class Frosty extends Application {

    private static final double W = 330;
    private static final double H = 590;

    private static final double BLUR_AMOUNT = 60;
    private static final Duration SLIDE_DURATION = Duration.seconds(0.4);

    private static final double UPPER_SLIDE_POSITION = 100;

    private static final Effect frostEffect =
        new BoxBlur(BLUR_AMOUNT, BLUR_AMOUNT, 3);

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        DoubleProperty y = new SimpleDoubleProperty(H);

        Node background = createBackground();
        Node frost      = freeze(background, y);
        Node content    = createContent();
        content.setVisible(false);

        Scene scene = new Scene(
                new StackPane(
                        background,
                        frost,
                        content
                )
        );

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        addSlideHandlers(y, content, scene);
    }

    // create a background node to be frozen over.
    private Node createBackground() {
        Image backgroundImage = new Image(
                getClass().getResourceAsStream("ios-screenshot.png")
        );
        ImageView background = new ImageView(backgroundImage);
        Rectangle2D viewport = new Rectangle2D(0, 0, W, H);
        background.setViewport(viewport);

        return background;
    }

    // create some content to be displayed on top of the frozen glass panel.
    private Label createContent() {
        Label label = new Label("The overlaid text is clear and the background below is frosty.");

        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 25px; -fx-text-fill: midnightblue;");
        label.setEffect(new Glow());
        label.setMaxWidth(W - 20);
        label.setWrapText(true);

        return label;
    }

    // add handlers to slide the glass panel in and out.
    private void addSlideHandlers(DoubleProperty y, Node content, Scene scene) {
        Timeline slideIn = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        SLIDE_DURATION,
                        new KeyValue(
                                y,
                                UPPER_SLIDE_POSITION
                        )
                )
        );

        slideIn.setOnFinished(e -> content.setVisible(true));

        Timeline slideOut = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        SLIDE_DURATION,
                        new KeyValue(
                                y,
                                H
                        )
                )
        );

        scene.setOnSwipeUp(e -> {
            slideOut.stop();
            slideIn.play();
        });

        scene.setOnSwipeDown(e -> {
            slideIn.stop();
            slideOut.play();
            content.setVisible(false);
        });

        // scroll handler isn't necessary if you have a touch screen.
        scene.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                slideOut.stop();
                slideIn.play();
            } else {
                slideIn.stop();
                slideOut.play();
                content.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    // create a frosty pane from a background node.
    private StackPane freeze(Node background, DoubleProperty y) {
        Image frostImage = background.snapshot(
                new SnapshotParameters(),
                null
        );
        ImageView frost = new ImageView(frostImage);

        Rectangle filler = new Rectangle(0, 0, W, H);
        filler.setFill(Color.AZURE);

        Pane frostPane = new Pane(frost);
        frostPane.setEffect(frostEffect);

        StackPane frostView = new StackPane(
                filler,
                frostPane
        );

        Rectangle clipShape = new Rectangle(0, y.get(), W, H);
        frostView.setClip(clipShape);

        clipShape.yProperty().bind(y);

        return frostView;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

**Source image**

Save this image parallel to the Java source as a file named `ios-screenshot.png` and have your build system copy it to the target directory for the binary output of the build.

[image: ios-screenshot]

**Answers to additional questions**

> "JDK 8," would that happen to be a requirement of this?

The sample code above is written against JDK 8.   Porting it back to JDK 7 by replacing the lambda calls with anonymous inner classes is pretty trivial.

In general, Java 7 is pretty dated for JavaFX work.  I advise upgrading at your earliest convenience to work with a Java 8 minimum version.

> initiating your Panes with arguments

More convenient constructors for most parent nodes is a [Java 8 feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#StackPane-javafx.scene.Node...-).  You can easily convert the Java 8 format:

```
 StackPane stack = new StackPane(child1, child2);
```

To Java 7:

```
 StackPane stack = new StackPane();
 stack.getChildren().setAll(child1, child2);
```

> will this working if the desktop is behind a frosty pane?

Not directly, you can create a new question for that.

**Update: Related Questions**

User created: [JavaFX effect on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663681/javafx-effect-on-background) to allow the frosted effect to apply to a window over a desktop background.

Another user created: [How do I create a JavaFX transparent stage with shadows on only the border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534204/how-do-i-create-a-javafx-transparent-stage-with-shadows-on-only-the-border) to apply a halo shadow effect around this window.

Comment: I'm speechless… That effect looks beautiful! It looks even more frosty than the image I used. @GGrec said "JDK 8," would that happen to be a requirement of this?

Comment: @Taconut He used lambda expressions in the example above. You could simply replace them to compile with JDK 7.

Comment: I got it working without the lambdas, but you're initiating your Panes with arguments. What's with that? Also, will this working if the desktop is behind a frosty pane?

Comment: Updated answer to address additional questions.

Comment: It seems to be working as I designed it lawl.  It may not work exactly like iOS 7 because I have never used iOS 7.  It is just a proof of concept.  You can use the edit button to modify it to make any changes you wish.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the background changes, the glass effect won't redraw. Otherwise, looks great.