# How to focus on applications behind the JavaFX window when clicking on transparent areas?

Tags: javafx

I'm creating a JavaFX stage with StageStyle.TRANSPARENT so I can fully customize the window. I've created my own shadow effect around the border of my window (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535316/652696)) to mimic the shadow around default application windows in OS X/Win7.

However, when a user clicks on the shadow around the border, the JavaFX stage will gain focus, which is understandable since the shadow is in the bounds of the JavaFX stage. Is there a way to cause clicking on the shadow part to "click through" and focus on the application/icon behind the JavaFX window? (Mouse transparency won't help for this).

So basically, when I click where the arrow is pointing in the image below, I want to focus on the text editor behind the JavaFX stage.

[image]

Comment: Are the `JavaFX stage` and the `text editor` part of the same application ?

Comment: No, the text editor is a separate application.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I think there is no solution for this.
Its OS dependent that you cant click through a window.

Comment: This [question proposes a solution for Windows (using JNA and native Windows event handling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957541/how-can-i-use-wm-nchittest-to-indicate-a-mouse-being-outside-the-application-are), though the author has not confirmed that the proposed solution would work and asked the question to gain assistance to create a working solution.