# How to set background color of StackPane node to transparent using javafx/css and fxml

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

Trying to create a drop-shadow to my `BorderPane`. I need to use a `StackPane` to allow room for the drop-shadow. The problem is I cannot seem to set the background of `StackPane` to transparent. I am using transparent style for my `primiaryStage`.

There are other example using javaFX which work but, I can't figure it out when using fxml.

```css
.StackPane{
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

This still shows a white background behind my BorderPane

```
public class Main extends Application {


    public static Stage Window;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
        Main.Window = primaryStage;
        Window.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Window.setResizable(false);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Homepage.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();    
        Window.setScene(new Scene(root));
        root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());

        Window.show();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of: [How do I create a JavaFX transparent stage with shadows on only the border?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534204/how-do-i-create-a-javafx-transparent-stage-with-shadows-on-only-the-border)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the window style might not work because the OS you are working on doesnt suppot that style. The documentation says about this:

> On some platforms decorations might not be available.

But for a workaround for the stackpane, you should provide an example image of what you are aiming for. Right now its rather unclear what exactually you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: using windows 7

Comment: added img to post

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using a scroll pane it would dynamically create stack panes under it during runtime. Using scenic view I was able to see the style class name as 'viewport' and could change the background color that way.

[image]