# Multiple Popups lag JavaFX application

Tags: javafx

I've made myself a convenient little method here that I use to spawn a floating piece of text at a given coordinate in my GUI.

```
public static void spawnLabel(final String text, final Color color, final double x, final double y) {
    final Popup pc = new Popup();
    final Label label = new Label(text);
    pc.getScene().setRoot(new AnchorPane(label));// Add label to Popup
    /* Style label */
    label.setTextFill(color);
    label.setBackground(null);
    label.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
    /* Set Popup positions */
    pc.setX(0);
    pc.setY(0);

    final TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), label);
    translateTransition.setFromY(y);
    translateTransition.setFromX(x);
    translateTransition.setToX(x);
    translateTransition.setToY(y - 25);
    translateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_OUT);
    final FadeTransition opacityTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(2), label);
    opacityTransition.setFromValue(0.7);
    opacityTransition.setToValue(0.0);

    pc.show(stage);// Uses the Stage of my app.

    translateTransition.play();
    opacityTransition.play();

    opacityTransition.setOnFinished(event -> pc.hide());
}
```

It simply takes in some text, a color, and a location and spawns a piece of text wherever the location is. The text will have the given color and will say whatever is passed into this method. This all works fine and uses a `Popup` object as a window and a `Label` object as the text node. The text will slowly move upwards and fade away.

Here's an image of the text that shows up:

[image: Flying text]

The problem I'm getting is that when the method is called multiple times, the program begins to "lag". (Usually 4-5 calls is enough to make the "lag" heavy.) What I mean by "lag" is that certain functions, like pressing buttons or hovering over some nodes, is greatly delayed.

For production, I plan to use this method quite intensively, so I can't afford to have a slight delay in common functions. **I don't know what causes this lag nor how to get rid of it** and I haven't found anything on google, so I've come here.

**Edit 1:** After repeatedly calling my method via a `Button` node in my GUI, the following exception occurs at random AND my hovering text stops showing up:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.stage.Window$TKBoundsConfigurator.apply(Window.java:1274)
at javafx.stage.Window$TKBoundsConfigurator.pulse(Window.java:1290)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:378)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PaintCollector.liveRepaintRenderJob(PaintCollector.java:320)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$ViewEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:831)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$ViewEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:792)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleViewEvent$368(GlassViewEventHandler.java:871)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleViewEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:870)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleViewEvent(View.java:539)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyResize(View.java:875)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow._setBounds(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.setBounds(Window.java:572)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setBounds(WindowStage.java:317)
at javafx.stage.Window$TKBoundsConfigurator.apply(Window.java:1274)
at javafx.stage.Window$TKBoundsConfigurator.pulse(Window.java:1290)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:378)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Edit 2:** I have not found *exactly* what causes this lag, but I have found a workaround that lets me get rid of it. I figured out that the lag persists when a `Pane` of any kind is placed in the `setRoot(...)` call of the fourth line of my method. I used an `AnchorPane` there as a wrapper for my `label` since the `label` wouldn't display when passed in directly. When I removed the `AnchorPane`, the lag disappeared.

Anyways, after repeated tries, I got the text to display in the `Popup` without an `AnchorPane` wrapper. My method is now as follows:

```
/**
 * Spawns a floating piece of text that flies upwards a little then
 * disappears. The source point of the text is specified via the {@code x}
 * and {@code y} parameters.
 *
 * @param text
 *            The text to render.
 * @param color
 *            The color of the rendered text.
 * @param x
 *            The starting x position of the text.
 * @param y
 *            The starting y position of the text.
 */
public static void spawnLabel(final String text, final Color color, final double x, final double y) {
    final Popup pc = new Popup();
    final Label label = new Label(text);
    final TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), label);
    final FadeTransition opacityTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(2), label);

    pc.getScene().setRoot(label);
    /* Style label */
    label.setTextFill(color);
    label.setBackground(null);
    label.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
    /* Set Popup positions */
    pc.setX(x);
    pc.setWidth(label.getMaxWidth());
    pc.setY(y - 50);
    /* Build transitions */
    translateTransition.setFromY(30);
    translateTransition.setFromX(0);
    translateTransition.setToX(0);
    translateTransition.setToY(5);
    translateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_OUT);
    opacityTransition.setFromValue(0.7);
    opacityTransition.setToValue(0.0);
    opacityTransition.setOnFinished(e -> pc.hide());
    /* Show the Popup */
    pc.show(stage);
    pc.setHeight(50);
    /* Play the transitions */
    translateTransition.play();
    opacityTransition.play();
}
```

Comment: Though i don't know why `Popup` causes such lags, i changed my popups to [transparent `Stage`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534204/how-do-i-create-a-javafx-transparent-stage-with-shadows-on-only-the-border) when i got same probrem.

Comment: Does the application use excessive amounts of CPU and/or RAM during or after displaying the popup?

Comment: @monolith52 Thank you, I'll look into doing that.

Comment: @sillyfly When I spam calls to the method, my CPU usage continuously increases to about 15x its original value (and doesn't go higher), but gradually returns to normal afterwards. The RAM however, continuously increases and has no apparent limit. It doesn't decrease either.