# Make Rectangle transparent

Tags: java, javafx-8, stage, scene

I need to make a drawn rectangle mouse transparent, in order to see the desktop.
The following code draws my rectangle. What should I add to get that ?
Thanks for help

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group group = new Group();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,20,200,200);

    rect.setArcHeight(15);
    rect.setArcWidth(15);

    rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    group.getChildren().add(rect);

    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? If you want to see the desktop, you will need the window to be transparent, but perhaps that is not what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the screen graph in JavaFX is in a hierarchical structure, to show desktop you need to also make the `Stage` and `Scene` transparent, and use shape "arithmetic":

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Group group = new Group();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 350, 300);
    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(20, 20, 200, 200);
    clip.setArcHeight(15);
    clip.setArcWidth(15);

    Shape shape = Shape.subtract(rect, clip);

    shape.setFill(Color.GRAY);
    group.getChildren().add(shape);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Later you can add draggable feature to the pane/group.

Comment: Thanks for help. The draggable feature is my next aim. Should I open a new question, because I cannot get it ?

Comment: @StéphaneGROSSMANN see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22960073) for the hint.. If it doesn't help yes you can open new question.

Comment: I put this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254354/resizing-a-substraction-shape
But no answer :-( Tks anyway

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the interior of the rectangle to be transparent, then all you need is

```
rect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but I'm not quite sure if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly as I don't get this mouse part of 'drawn rectangle mouse transparent' - your rectangle should be transparent?

You have to change the opacity of a rectangle:
rect.opacityProperty().set(0.5);

Comment: if you mean this :  rect.setStroke(new javafx.scene.paint.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); turns it to black

Comment: With 1, the rectangle is black too :-(

Comment: Check the edited answer. :) Sadly you cannot just apply a transparent color. You have to specify an alpha channel of a rectangle (strange, strange...). So closer to 0.0 is more transparent 1.0 is solid.

Comment: Great ! That's what I wanted. Thanks a lot :-)