# Transparent text Shape

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to create a filled rectangle with transparent text in it. So you can see through the letters what's painted under the shape.
There is a Text Shape in javafx. But it allows to access only the area within the letters: filling, stroke, color, etc. It is not possible to fill its rectangular borders leaving text unfilled.
There is a rectangular Shape. But I didn't manage to find out how to "cut off" text from it.
Maybe there is any way to mix those two? To create an Object with both inner-text and outer-text areas accessible for filling with color?
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26230057/4629012) and especially on the method `Shape.subtract(pShape1, pShape2)`.

Comment: @Pagbo, thanks a lot! I was searching this solution for a few months!