# A javafx stage with a transparent background and decorations

Tags: java, javafx, background

I'd like to create a simple protactor in javafx. To that aim, I need to create a stage with a transparent backgrount but WITH decorations. I mean : I still want to be able to move my window or close it when finished.
I tried to use those properties :

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

But all the window disappear : the background AND the decoration.
I also tried to use :

```
stage.setOpacity(0.9);
```

In that case, all the window, background and decoration is partially translucent and that's not what I want to get.
I would like a stage with a full opaque decoration and a fully transparent background on which I'll can draw a protractor partially opaque, like if I was using the real object on my screen.

Does someone could give me a tip to do that ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make content within a JavaFX Scene transparent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110420/how-do-i-make-content-within-a-javafx-scene-transparent)

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Well... I'm a bit surprised to find something impossible in JAVA but, ok. I have to find another solution. Maybe 2 windows, a opaque one and a transparent one, "linked" together. When I'll move the opaque one, it'll move the transparent one. Same thing if I close it. I'll try that solution.