# Is there any way to make a Stage transparent without using StageStyle.TRANSPARENT

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is there any way to make a Stage transparent without using StageStyle.TRANSPARENT? I want the stage to be transparent, but using `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)` causes other kinds of side-effects that I do not want; one of which, for example, is removing the border, but there are others.

Comment: hmm .. don't understand - what _exactly_ do you want to be transparent? A transparent window is .. well, transparent everywhere, including its decorations (border, title area). Just having the space filled by the scene transparent is not possible, afaik (but might be wrong)

Comment: Imagine that you have a normal window with the titlebar and everything, but in the middle of the window you had a rectangle where you could see through it. The only way I can think of is to make StageStyle.TRANSPARENT, but then you would have to re-implement all the native window styling and behaviors.

Comment: You are correct: "you would have to re-implement all the native window styling and behaviors." By using `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`, you have basically told Windows that **you** will handle all of the Window decorations with your JavaFX code.

Comment: @Zephyr Right, so my question is whether there is a way to do transparency without using `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`, because I don't want to tell Windows that I will handle all the decorations.

Comment: You could use something like the [`copyBackground()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663681/javafx-effect-on-background) method in this answer, though that is a pure hack and I'm guessing that approach will have issues if you try to accomplish it in a relatively robust manner, so I don't necessarily recommend it.