# How to apply a blur only to a rectangular area within a pane?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Let's say I've got a `StackPane` which has a `BackgroundImage` as background and another `StackPane` (or another component, if neccessary) as a child. The child covers only a part of the parent `StackPane`.

I'd like to know how to apply a `GaussianBlur` just to the area the child covers, so that the `BackgroundImage`is blurry in this area.

The size of the child changes when the parent is resized. It would be perfect to get a solution that will resize just in time, too.

Comment: It's a little bit different, but some of the techniques involved for this question are the same: [Frosted Glass Effect in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622034/frosted-glass-effect-in-javafx).

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the suggestion - I've had a look at it, but didn't find something I could apply to my situation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it manually, you can use the [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) function to create a snapshot image, blur it and apply it to the child every time the parent is resized.

However, invoking snapshot all the time will cause performance loss. I rather suggest you create 2 images, one normal and one blurred, and display a [viewport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) of the blurred one.

Here's a more "complex" example with a circle where the viewport isn't sufficient. The clip method is used in this case:

```
public class Lens extends Application {

    Image image = new Image( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/800px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");

    CirclePane circlePane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ImageView normalImageView = new ImageView( image);
        ImageView blurredImageView = new ImageView( image);
        blurredImageView.setEffect(new GaussianBlur( 40));

        Group root = new Group();

        root.getChildren().addAll( normalImageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // pane with clipped area
        circlePane = new CirclePane( blurredImageView);
        makeDraggable( circlePane);

        root.getChildren().addAll( circlePane);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private class CirclePane extends Pane {

        ImageView blurredImageView;
        ImageView clippedView = new ImageView();

        public CirclePane( ImageView blurredImageView) {

            this.blurredImageView = blurredImageView;

            // new imageview
            update();

            getChildren().addAll( clippedView);

        }

        public void update() {

            // create circle
            Circle circle = new Circle( 200);
            circle.relocate( getLayoutX(), getLayoutY());

            // clip image by circle
            blurredImageView.setClip(circle);

            // non-clip area should be transparent
            SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

            // new image from clipped image
            WritableImage wim = null;
            wim = blurredImageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);

            clippedView.setImage( wim);

        }

    }

    // make node draggable
    class DragContext { 
        double x;
        double y; 
    } 

    public void makeDraggable( Node node) {

        final DragContext dragDelta = new DragContext();

        node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

            dragDelta.x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();

        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {

            node.relocate( mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x, mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
            circlePane.update();

        });

    }

}
```

Just click on the circle and drag it around.

[image]