# JavaFX blur whole window

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to implement something like modal popus in my application. To make them more clear, I decided to blur out whole window and place popus in front of it.

The problem is that JavaFX blurring creates artifacts when applied to a whole window:

[image: alt]

Notice a white border — it should not exist.

---

My code is:

```
public void enableBlur() {
    ColorAdjust adj = new ColorAdjust(0, -0.9, -0.5, 0);
    GaussianBlur blur = new GaussianBlur(55); // 55 is just to show edge effect more clearly.
    adj.setInput(blur)
    rootPanel.setEffect(adj);
}
```

So the effect is applied to root content panel.

---

**P.S.** The question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622034/frosted-glass-effect-in-javafx) since I think that provided solution suffers from the same edge effect, but it is not so clearly visible because the content of form is not so dark as here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frosted Glass Effect in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622034/frosted-glass-effect-in-javafx)

Comment: I tried taking a snapshot and then blurring a snapshot. But it does not works.

Also I think that edge effect is also present in that solution. It's more subtle, however, because the background is light and border effect is white.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `fill` of the `Scene` to the background color.

In the following example you can toggle between no fill (`null`) and the background color (`Color.BLACK`) (if you can find the button through that blur effect).

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("If you can read this, the blur isn't working!");

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
    ColorAdjust adj = new ColorAdjust(0, -0.9, -0.5, 0);
    GaussianBlur blur = new GaussianBlur(55); // 55 is just to show edge effect more clearly.
    adj.setInput(blur);
    root.setEffect(adj);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200, null);

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        scene.setFill(scene.getFill() == Color.BLACK ? null : Color.BLACK);
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```